# Emmet with JSX in PhpStorm

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, jsx, emmet

I'm trying to work on React with PhpStorm and my Emmet doesn't work on my `render()` function. My JS is set to React JSX and my Emmet enabled JSX.

I've read some of post saying that PhpStorm Emmet and JSX was little bit painful, maybe there's no more issue today ??

Comment: Does Emmet work for you in HTML? a screen recording of the issue would be helpful

Comment: My file was a .js and not a .jsx, that's the mistake...

Comment: it shouldn't be the issue if the javascript language version is set to *React JSX*... Emmet should work in `.js` files as well as in `.jsx`

Comment: It should complete HTML in my render() even if it's in a .js file?

Comment: yes, exactly - with language version set to *React JSX* `.js` and `.jsx` files are treated equally

Comment: Ok thx for the info, i'm newbie in react :)

Answer (score 0):

My file was a .js and not a .jsx, that's the mistake.